# Auto Refresh React Table upon success of the delete action server side

Tags: reactjs, server-side, react-table

How can i refresh the react-table upon editing/deleting a data (server-side based), Here's my code so far

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { useTable, usePagination } from 'react-table'
// import {TableContainer} from './?'
import Table from './TableContainer'
import axios from 'axios';

// Let's add a fetchData method to our Table component that will be used to fetch
// new data when pagination state changes
// We can also add a loading state to let our table know it's loading new data

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'name',
            accessor: 'name',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Last Name',
            accessor: 'lastName',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: 'Info',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'Age',
            accessor: 'age',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Visits',
            accessor: 'visits',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Status',
            accessor: 'status',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Profile Progress',
            accessor: 'progress',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Action',
            accessor: '',
            id: 'edit',
            accessor: 'id',
            Cell: ({value}) => (<button onClick={() => editData(value)} data-id={value}>Edit</button>)
          },
          
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )

  // We'll start our table without any data
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = React.useState(0)
  const [ totalPages, setTotalPages ] = useState(0);
  const [ sizePerPage, setSizePerPage ] = useState(10);
  const [ page, setPage ] = useState(0);
  const [ filtered, setFiltered ] = useState("");
  const fetchIdRef = React.useRef(0)

  const fetchData = React.useCallback(({ pageSize, pageIndex,filtered }) => {
      console.log(filtered);
      setLoading(true);

        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/schools?q=${filtered}&sizePerPage=${pageSize}&page=${pageIndex+1}`)
        .then((res)=> {
            setData(res.data.data);
            setSizePerPage(res.data.meta.per_page)
            setPage(res.data.meta.current_page)
            setPageCount(Math.ceil(res.data.meta.total  / pageSize))
            setLoading(false)
        });
  }, [])

  function editData(name) { 
    setLoading(true);
    console.log(name)
    console.log(sizePerPage);
    axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/schools/${name}`)

    .then((res) =>{
      
      //  fetchData(sizePerPage);
    })
  }


  return (
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        fetchData={fetchData}
        loading={loading}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        filtered={filtered}
        filterable
      />
  )
}

export default App
```

When I call the fetch data upon the response, it can't access the callback param of *pageSize,pageIndex, filtered* I've already try to call it with params but it gives me an error that the pageSize,pageIndex are now undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: fixed it by adding listeners when the API endpoints for updating triggers